# $A\rightarrow B$ and $\Pi x:A.b(x)\in B$

Tags: logic, type-theory, lambda-calculus

I have a question about the following two formulas (where both $A,B:\textsf{Prop}$ and $x$ is not a free variable in $B$):
$$A\rightarrow B\quad\quad\quad\Pi x:A.b(x)\in B$$
where $b(x)\in B$ is a membership type (equivalent to $\textsf{Id}(b(x),b(x),B)$ using the notation of identity type) indicating that $b(x)$ is an inhabitant of $B$. It appears to me that they are equivalent. From $\Pi x:A.b(x)\in B$, by the elimination rule of $\in$, it is easy to deduce $\Pi x:A.B$, which is in fact equivalent to $A\rightarrow B$. So we have the following:
$$(\Pi x:A.b(x)\in B)\rightarrow(A\rightarrow B)$$
But what about the other direction? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should probably say what type theory this is supposed to be. For instance, in Martin-löf type theory, it doesn't make much sense to consider the identity type to be a 'membership type', because it must already be the case that $b(x) : B$ in order for $\mathsf{Id}_B(b(x),b(x))$ to even be a well-formed type.

Comment: @DanDoel I am using Constable's Computational Type Theory, which is a variant of MLTT. That definition comes from their NuPRL, $t\in T$ is an abbreviation of $t=_Tt$ or $Id(t,t,T)$.

Comment: @EminiJask do you have a constructor for identity types like $\operatorname{refl}$ available? (the introduction rule for $\operatorname{refl}$ in the ML type theory I know is that, if $C$ is a type and $c:C$, we can judge $\operatorname{refl}_c:\operatorname{Id}(c,c,C)$)

Comment: Right, it's the same thing. Since the membership type $c\in C$ is just an abbreviation of $Id(c,c,C)$, they have the same inference rules.

Comment: NuPRL is rather different from MLTT. The former is based on types being partial equivalence relations on a fixed semantic domain. So typing is propositional, and terms can have many types. By contrast, in MLTT, terms have essentially one intrinsic type, and the identity type is only well defined for terms known to have that given type. Just copying similar looking things from one to another won't necessarily make sense.

Comment: @DanDoel I'm not familiar with NuPRL unfortunately, and a quick google search didn't reveal much information. does the answer I gave below still make sense in that context?

Comment: I think your answer makes sense. NuPRL only factors in in that $x =_T y$ in NuPRL is *not* the same thing as $Id_T(x,y)$ in Martin-löf type theory, so one can't just copy something from NuPRL and replace equality with the MLTT identity type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me expand a bit on Dan Doel's point. In Martin-Löf type theory, to make a judgement that $\operatorname{Id}(b(x),b(x),B)$ is a type, you need to have already judged that $b(x)$ is of type $B$. In particular, for $$\prod_{x:A}\operatorname{Id}(b(x),b(x),B)$$ to be a type, you need to know that we can deduce $b(x):B$ from $x:A$. This means you must assume that $\lambda x.b(x)$ is a term of type $A\rightarrow B$ for your question to even make sense. If we do assume this – ie, if we assume that we have already judged $\lambda x.b(x):(A\rightarrow B)$ – then we *can* solve your problem, but it's perhaps a slightly unsatisfying solution:

In Martin-Löf type theory, we have the "reflexive" constructor for identity types, which I will denote $\operatorname{refl}$. The introduction rule for $\operatorname{refl}$ is that, if $C$ is a type and we have judged $c:C$, then we can judge $\operatorname{refl}_c:\operatorname{Id}(c,c,C)$. If you have this construction in your type theory, then $\prod_{x:A}\operatorname{Id}(b(x),b(x),B)$ in fact *always* holds, with a proof given by the term $\lambda x.\operatorname{refl}_{b(x)}$. Since we know $b(x):B$ for any $x:A$, it is clear that this will be well-typed. If you wish, we can then construct a proof of $$(A\rightarrow B)\rightarrow\prod_{x:A}\operatorname{Id}(b(x),b(x),B),$$ simply by considering the term $\lambda f.\lambda x.\operatorname{refl}_{b(x)}$.  Conversely, we can construct a proof of  $$\prod_{x:A}\operatorname{Id}(b(x),b(x),B)\rightarrow (A\rightarrow B)$$ by the term $\lambda g.\lambda x.b(x)$; since we already know $\lambda x.b(x):(A\rightarrow B)$, this will be well-typed.

If this is the answer you're looking for, great! However, there's not much "moral" content in it, as the terms we construct don't ever use their first arguments. This is why I'm not sure if we're understanding your question correctly.

Comment: Yes, I have the same doubt because the first argument is not used. But it appears that we can take it to be a theorem, even though it is mainly due to the presupposition of the well-formedness of $Id(b(x),b(x),B)$, right?

Comment: @EminiJask yep, exactly! :) the two terms given above provide a proof

Comment: Let me ask a further question. Let $\Gamma\vdash f: A\rightarrow B$. In this case, if we follow the above reasoning, we can actually reach $\Gamma\vdash(\lambda x)\textsf{refl}(f(x)):\Pi x:A.\textsf{Id}(f(x),f(x),B)$. Is that right?

Comment: @EminiJask exactly!! :)

Comment: Thanks a lot! :-) Have a good night!